# JSF pages from Entities Clases

Tags: jsf, netbeans, xhtml, wizard

I've a problem when I use de wizard of Netbeans to create "JSF pages from Entities Clases". By default the wizard generate .jsp pages and I need .xhtm pages.
How I can change the type of JSF pages that generate the wizard?

Thanks!!

Comment: Using a more modern version of Netbeans? And suggestion: don't use these kinds of 'generators'. They don't generate the best code and makes it difficult for you to maintain

Comment: I use the 8.0.2 version, I think that I have to configurate the wizard, but I don't know where.

Comment: Maybe you should try version 8.2, for me there is no such entry in the file creation wizard, but therefore there are others which are able to create JSF files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally been able to solve my problem.

The steps for change the "JSF pages from Entities Clases" defined by default are:

Over the web project --> Click Right bottom--> Propierties.

In categories (on the right) we have to select Frameworks (Java Server Faces).

Now we open the "configuration" tab and choose "Preferred Page Language": "Facelets".

Facelets=.xhtml

For a better explanation see the image below:

[facelets.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbZ4q.png)